# IP address validation while the user is typing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, regex

I'm beginner in angularjs. I create a costume directive which validate IP address on keyperss event of textbox. It's work good but, I think there will be more efficient way implementation with use of regx or any other thing like parser or filter etc.

please help me improve this.

```js
//Declare Main and sub modules
angular.module('CompanyApp', []);

//Initialize variables when DOM is ready
angular.module('CompanyApp').run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) { } ]);

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('CompanyApp').controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', TestCtrl]);

    function TestCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.ipAddress = '';
       }
})()
angular.module('CompanyApp').directive("ipValidator", function () {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'A'
    directive.compile = function (element, attributes) {
        var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keypress", function (e) {
                var key = e.key;
                var code = e.keyCode;
                var txt = element.val();                
                txt += key;
                var len = txt.length;
                var lastchar = txt.charAt(len-2);
                var txtList = txt.split('.');
                if ((len == 1 ||lastchar==='.')&& code == 46) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else if (!(code <= 57 && code >= 46) || len >= 16 || txtList.length > 4) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    txtList.forEach(function (value) {
                        var intValue = parseInt(value);
                        if (intValue > 255 || intValue < 0) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });

                }
                          });
        }
        return link;
    }
    return directive;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div name="divCompanyContainer" ng-app="CompanyApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="Init()">
<input type="text" ng-model="ipAddress" ip-validator placeholder="Ip address"  /> <br />
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question?  Here on SO you have an issue and we try to help you.  What is you specific problem?

Comment: @tukan  sir, I just want to know there may other alternative way  to implement this with reduced line of code and efforts.

Comment: Actually, in the code that you have you can type this invalid IP: **`012.002.0255.01`**.

Comment: @Danny Fardy Jhonston Bermúdez opps... yes sir, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets talk about **regular expression**. Then, the **algorithm** we could use.

## Regular expressions and IP

*(Note: the IP regexps came from [Regular-expressions.info - How to Find or Validate an IP Address](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html).)*

The whole regular expression for an IP address could be:

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

- You can see that the three first bytes are both checked by the same pattern below (surrounded by `^` and `$`):

  ```
    ^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.)$
  ```
- The fourth byte is different:

  ```
    ^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
  ```

## Simple algorithm

(Note: I'm only considering the **`keypress`** event.)

Since the IP is **validated incrementally**, we could assume at each validation that **a part** is **already correct**.

**The algorithm would be, for each key press**:

1. **Get** an **array** of **entered bytes** separated by a dot `.`
2. If the array contains more than four items, the user entered an extra dot after a valid IP, input is rejected, **return `false`**
3. If the **penultimate** byte is an **empty string**, the user tried to enter a **second dot**, input is rejected, **return `false`**
4. If the **last byte** is an **empty string**, that's okay because the user just **entered a dot**, **return `true`**
5. The **last byte** is not empty, let's check it with the relevant regexp; if it matches its regexp then **return `true`** else **return `false`**.

Below a working snippet you could adapt.

```js
var first3BytesRg = /^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))$/;
var fourthByteRg = /^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;

document.getElementById("ip").onkeypress = preventInvalid;

function preventInvalid(e) {
  return validateIP(e.target.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
}

function validateIP(ip) {
  var splitted = ip.split(".");
  var nb = splitted.length;
  
  if (nb > 4) return false;
  if (splitted[nb - 2] == "") return false;
  if (splitted[nb - 1] == "") return true;
  
  
  if (nb < 4) {
    return first3BytesRg.test(splitted[nb - 1]);
  }
  
  return fourthByteRg.test(splitted[nb - 1]);
}
```

```html
IP <input type="text" id="ip" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that's actuality I want.

Comment: Be aware that this validates the ip `0.0.0.0` as **valid**

Comment: @dewey, you're right.

Comment: And it also accepts adresses with a leading zero. Examples: https://regex101.com/r/TG0grL/1 This should be avoided, as explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/857603/are-ip-addresses-with-and-without-leading-zeroes-the-same/857618#857618

Comment: @dewey, sounds like the provided regex assumes it's a decimal-notation value.